# i have some view inside relative layout after using exapnd/collaps animation height remain same but i want to change according java code

Tags: java, android

i have `RelativeLayout` as parent inside that i have many view like `Button`, `TextView`, `EditText` on click button  i want to expand/collapse it..but under some condition view visibility is gone/visible but after visibility gone the height remain same. i am taking  dynamic height using  `OnPreDrawListener`

```
mcheckin_relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        mcheckin_relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        mcheckin_relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);  

                        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                        mcheckin_relativeLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
                        height = mcheckin_relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();


                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

/*** using this for exapnd the relative layout ***/

```
private void expand(RelativeLayout layout, int layoutHeight) {
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ValueAnimator animator = slideAnimator(layout, 0, layoutHeight);
    animator.start();
}
```

/*** using this for Collapsethe relative layout ***/

```
private void collapse(final RelativeLayout layout) {
    int finalHeight = layout.getHeight();
    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(layout, finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {

            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}
```

Comment: if there is anyone to answer this Q?

Answer (score 0):

make it invisible it may help

```
mcheckin_relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: bro it not working the some view that has visibility.gone still take space while animation of exapand